# Add-Ins in Exchange 2016 CU6 not working, getting "The Url property on the ExchangeService object must be set."

Tags: exchange, outlook-addin, exchange-2016

I hava a problem that I can no longer use Add-Ins in Exchange.

I get following error: The Url property on the ExchangeService object must be set.

If the user tries to send an mail he recives a mesage that the addins couldnt be loaded.

The browser tries to load following URL for the user:

```
/owa/service.svc?action=GetExtensibilityContext&EP=1&UA=0&ID=-34&AC=1
```

But the server response with 500

For the below screenshoot the browser reaches following URL

```
/ecp/DDI/DDIService.svc/GetList?ActivityCorrelationID=df57039d-c079-2b98-0eff-7bb7aae8f7d6&schema=OrgClientExtension&msExchEcpCanary=CMfYG9QZXUmC2nW4kA51YaDtFVHn6dQICgb6-7g_2u8UUwIa23UgkVCWczoT3s6ds6iB1LNnKOk.`
```

For this the response is 200 but the body contains a json object that contains the displayed error.

```
d   Object
    __type  JsonDictionaryOfanyTypeResults:ECP
    Cmdlets [1]
        0   Get-App
    ErrorRecords    [1]
        0   Object
            __type  ErrorRecord:ECP
            Message The Url property on the ExchangeService object must be set.
    Informations    []
    IsDDIEnabled    false
    Warnings    []
    Output  []
```

[image: Exchange ECP]

What URL is missing, and where did I need to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why, but my Server just lost its configuration.
I reented the correct values using:

```
Set-OWAVirtualDirectory –Identity "OWA (default web site)" -ExternalURL 
Set-OWAVirtualDirectory –Identity "OWA (default web site)" -InternalURL 

Set-OABVirtualDirectory –Identity "OAB (default web site)" -ExternalURL 
Set-OABVirtualDirectory –Identity "OAB (default web site)" -InternalURL 

Set-ECPVirtualDirectory –Identity "ECP (default web site)" -ExternalURL 
Set-ECPVirtualDirectory –Identity "ECP (default web site)" -InternalURL 

Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory –Identity "EWS (default web site)" -ExternalUrl
Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory –Identity "EWS (default web site)" -InternalUrl

Set-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory –Identity "Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync (default web site)" -ExternalURL
Set-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory –Identity "Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync (default web site)" -InternalURL
```

And it worked again.